# Firestore get count for a collection not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code:

```
import { getCountFromServer } from 'firebase/firestore'
useEffect(()=> {
    const getCount = async () => {
        const collection = userDB().collection('invoices')
        const query = collection.where('status', '==', 'paid')
        const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(query)
        setCount(snapshot.data().count)
    }
    getCount().catch(err=> console.log(err))
}, [user, collectionRef, filterKey, filterValue])
```

Where `userDB()` is the same as `db.collection('users').doc(userid')`

Yet this throughs an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_t')
    at gn (index.esm2017.js:4251:1)
    at bu (index.esm2017.js:13685:1)
    at Ca.run (index.esm2017.js:16797:1)
    at index.esm2017.js:20050:1
```

I have followed the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#web-version-9_1

Currently using:

```
"firebase": "^9.15.0",
```

`userDB` is defined in a ts file like so:

```
export const userDB = () => {
  let user = auth.currentUser
  return db.collection('users').doc(user?.uid)
}
```

Here is the initlizer file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

const  firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp ({
    ...keys
});

export const Providers = {
    google: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

const db = firebaseApp.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth();
const Fire = firebaseApp

export  {db, Fire, auth}
```

Comment: Can you share complete code so we can see where `userDB()` is defined? Are you using compat SDK to initialize Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You should not uses both `compat` and `modular` SDKs together. The compat version does not support count queries. I would recommend updating your code to use the new syntax:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } 'firebase/auth';

const  firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    ...keys
});

export const Providers = {
    google: new GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

const db = getFirestore()
const auth = getAuth();

export { db, auth }
```

```
import { db } from '...'
import { collection, query, where, getCountFromServer } from 'firebase/firestore'

useEffect(()=> {
    const getCount = async () => {
        const q = query(collection(db, 'invoices'), where('status', '==', 'paid'))
        const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(q)
        setCount(snapshot.data().count)
    }
    getCount().catch(err=> console.log(err))
}, [user, collectionRef, filterKey, filterValue])
```